# YouTube API - how to fetch all playlists of a channel, even the ones who were added from other channels

Tags: api, youtube, external, playlist

I stumbled across this problem as I wanted to transfer all playlists (my own and those who I added from other channels) to another channel.

The code I use returns only my own playlists and not the ones I added to my channel from another channel.

I tested this behaviour in the target account which contains a private playlist I created and two playlists from another channel. The script I created uses oauth in order to 'see' my private playlist, but is not able to find the certainly public playlist from the other channel.

My code:

```
    request = youtube.playlists().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails,status",
        channelId="UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
        maxResults=25
    )
```

maxResults does not play a role here as I only have got all together three playlist on the test account.
The playlist from another channel is clearly visible when I use the "Library" link and scroll down to "Playlists".

I would appreciate any hint to solve this *'mystery'*. TIA!

---

This is how I added the playlist from the other channel:

- go to the other channel
- list the playlists
- click on "VIEW THE FULL PLAYLIST"
- click on the icon which looks like a sandwich combined with a plus sign (hovering on it gives 'save playlist')

Comment: Not sure if this is possible with YouTube Data API, consider search or post a issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803). If you can consider it, use web-scraping.